# FormGroup in angular does not correctly see single changes of its children if they listen to each other through valueChanges

Tags: angular, observable, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I have got simple situation. There is a html form with two fields:

- firstName
- lastName

I want `lastName` to change for something when user changes `firstName`. I implemented it through valueChanges observable in Angular (8).

Besides I have two subscription to listen and log changes:

- one on whole form
- one on `lastName`

Here is how it is implemented:

```js
 ngOnInit(){
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl('', {updateOn: 'blur'}),
      lastName: new FormControl('', {updateOn: 'blur'}),
    });
    this.form.get('lastName').valueChanges.subscribe(value => console.log('lastName', value));
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(value => console.log('Value', value));

    this.form.get('firstName').valueChanges
      .subscribe(firstName => {
        this.form.get('lastName').setValue(`firstName ${firstName} ${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`);
      });
  }
```

In general - from a user point of view - this behaves as expected. User changes `firstName` and then `lastName` changes itself.

But when I look at the console log, here is what I've got:

```
lastName firstName test 850 
Value > {firstName: "test", lastName: "firstName test 850"}
Value > {firstName: "test", lastName: "firstName test 850"}
```

I expected two logs from whole, but one with first name changed, and second with lastName changed.
Something more like this:

```
Value > {firstName: "test", lastName: ""}
lastName firstName test 850 
Value > {firstName: "test", lastName: "firstName test 850"}
```

Here is a whole example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ps29ue).

Ok, so when I changed a way I update `lastName` from this:

```
this.form.get('lastName').setValue(`firstName ${firstName} ${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`);
```

to this:

```
setTimeout(() => this.form.get('lastName').setValue(`firstName ${firstName} ${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`));
```

then logs are in order which I expected:

```
Value > {firstName: "test", lastName: ""}
lastName firstName test 850 
Value > {firstName: "test", lastName: "firstName test 850"}
```

However, `setTimeout` seems to be tricky hack here.
Here is whole code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yltmqx).

The question is:
What is going on here? Why FormGroups works in that way? 
Is there a pattern to process such events in Angular (when one form affects another)?

Answer (score 3):

## This is how event loop works

What's happening in both cases :

### Without setTimeout

1. User set firstName
2. `firstName.valueChanges` is added to `EventLoop` queue
3. `EventLoop` runs and call operation `firstName.valueChanges`
4. `lastName.setValue` is called
5. `lastName.setValue` add `lastName.valueChanges` and `form.valueChanges` to eventLoop queue
6. `lastName.valueChanges` add `form.valueChanges` to eventLoop queue
7. `lastName.valueChanges` is dequeued
8. `form.valueChanges` (from `lastName.valueChanges`) is dequeued
9. `form.valueChanges` (from `firstName.valueChanges`) is dequeued

### With setTimeout

1. User set firstName
2. `firstName.valueChanges` is added to `EventLoop` queue
3. `EventLoop` runs and call operation `firstName.valueChanges`
4. `setTimeout(lastName.setValue)` is not called but added to the event loop queue
5. `firstName.valueChanges` adds `form.valueChanges` to event loop queue
6. `setTimeout` is dequeued, he sets `lastName` value and adds `lastName.valueChanges` to tevent loop queue
7. `form.valueChanges` (from `firstName.valueChanges`) is dequeued
8. `lastName.valueChanges` is dequeued and adds `form.valueChanges` to event loop queue
9. `form.valueChanges` (from `lastName.valueChanges`) is dequeued